# Why my Ajax posting script not working?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have barely created a script (as I'm just a beginner in ajax), in fact I have copied some part (ajax script) of it from somewhere. But when I click on the the link (vote up / vote down) nothing happens not even the value in Mysql database changes, but on click the submit button I got a change in my MySql Database! Here is my code --

**-:::- HTML PART (test.php) -:::-**

```
<html>
       <title>
               TEST
       </title>
       <head>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.4.4.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                        function vote(type)
                        {
                          $.ajax({
                              'url': 'test.func.php',
                              'type': 'POST',
                              'dataType': 'json', 
                              'data': {type: type},
                              'success': function(data)
                               {
                                   if(data.status)
                                   {
                                       if(data.voted)
                                        {
                                             $(document).ready(function () {
                                               $("span#status"+type).attr("innerHTML","You have voted up!");
                                             });
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                             $(document).ready(function () {
                                               $("span#status"+type).attr("innerHTML","You have voted Down!");
                                             });
                                        }
                                    }
                               },
                               beforeSend: function()
                                 {
                                      $(document).ready(function () {
                                       $("span#status"+type).attr("innerHTML","Voting....");
                                      });
                                 },
                                  'error': function(data)
                                  {
                                    $(document).ready(function () {
                                      $("span#status"+type).attr("innerHTML","An error occureed");
                                    });
                                  }
                                });
                          }
                </script>
       </head>
       <body>
              <a href="#" onclick="vote('up')" > Vote Up </a>
              <span id="status_up" ></span>
              <br>
              OR
              </br>
              <a href="#" onclick="vote('down')" > Vote Down </a>
              <span id="status_down" ></span>
       </body>
</html>
```

**-:::- PHP PART (test.func.php) -:::-**

```
<?php

    function db_connect($i)
    {
         if(isset($i))
         {
              if(mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root'))
              {
                   if(mysql_select_db($i))
                   {
                        return;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        echo 'ERROR';
                   }
              }
              else
              {
                  echo 'ERROR';
              }
         }
         else
         {
             echo 'ERROR';
         }
    }
if($_POST)
{
 db_connect('tests');
 $vote_type=$_POST['type'];
 $post_id = '123';
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE post_id='$post_id'");
 $cur_vote_get = mysql_fetch_array($query);
 $vote_up = $cur_vote_get['votes']+1;
 $vote_down = $cur_vote_get['votes']-1;
 if($vote_type=='up')
 {
   mysql_query("UPDATE test SET votes='$vote_up' WHERE post_id='$post_id'");
   return json_encode(array("status" => true, "voted" => true));
 }
 elseif($vote_type=='down')
 {
   mysql_query("UPDATE test SET votes='$vote_down' WHERE post_id='$post_id'");
   return json_encode(array("status" => true, "voted" => false));
 }
}

?>
```

**JavaScript Error solved!**

**Everything Solved!**

As I'm very new to Ajax so I'm not able to find any solution to this.

Comment: What does your console say? are there any javascript errors? also, Add some alerts to see where your code gets and where it does not...

Comment: Have you used fiddler or firebug to check if the ajax call is even being attempted?

Comment: No, I haven't, but I will in a minute.

Comment: Also, if I were you, I would first try running the page which does the MySQL by accessing it directly apart from AJAX.  Then, at least you know if it's the PHP or the AJAX which is the problem.

Comment: Have you considered adding a `'error': function(){}` on your AJAX call?

Comment: Hey I got the problem in my Ajax code it is, I forgot to add `,` after `beforeSend: ...`! But still it is not working! Please if you have any ideas let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the new error code?  Can you see the call to ajax being made in firebug?

Comment: Error does not expects any parameter in AJAX calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not echoing the json, you're echoing random text ('Vote up'), which will break the ajax json parser.

Remove the `echo 'Voted!';` and try `echo json_encode(array("status" => true, "voted" => false));`.

Also you can skip the `SELECT` query and do : `UPDATE test SET votes=votes+1 WHERE post_id='$post_id'`

Comment: Thanks buddy this worked even better! It is now showing messages! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, Good luck with your ajax trip, it's a fun trip once you get the hang of it!

Answer (score 3):

If that's STRICTLY your code, (I mean, if you've just literally copy/pasted it from your real .php file), there's a typo error in the second script block of the first .php document.

javasript -> javasCript

Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks friguron it worked! But now I'm not getting any messages! Please help me with this.